# How do i implement sorting and filtering in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm pretty new to django and i am working on a project where i need to let users sort or filter listed results by brand or manufacturer and sort using prices(*highest to lowest or vice versa*).How should i approach this problem?

Comment: How do you currently *display* the list of products?

Comment: i am currently using a class based  `ListView`, but i'm open to any suggestions including changing how i display my products to function view, i'm comfortable with either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ListView class, you can override the function of get queryset and if you are passing the logic you can override the query with those parameters. For example::

```
class ExampleListView(ListView):
    model = example

    def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = Goods.objects.all()
      if self.request.GET.get("manufacturer"):
        selection = self.request.GET.get("browse")
        queryset = Goods.objects.filter(manufacturer = selection)
      return queryset
```

Or can you use something like [this](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) an out of box solution for you filtering needs on django and you can add filters out of your models fields, by defining a filterview.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
query = Goods.objects
  sort_by = request.GET.pop('sort_by', 'id')  
  for k, v in request.GET.items():
       query.filter(k=v)
  result = query.order_by(sort_by)
```